# Imported three.js module OrbitControls "not defined"

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

Javascript and HTML newbie here:

I'm trying to display a 3D model (.gltf file) in a website with controls (pan, zoom, etc.), using the javascript three.js OrbitControls module. In spite of using `<script type="module">` tags in the HTML to load OrbitControls, when I try to load the page, I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: OrbitControls is not defined` from firefox. I can successfully render the image if I do not include the statement defining the controls, but do include the import tag.

Brief code:

--HTML:

```
<head>
  <!-- Imports for three.js and GLTFLoader.js, both seem to be working -->
  <script type="module"> 
    import { OrbitControls } from "https://unpkg.com/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js"; 
  </script>
  <script src="script.js" defer="defer"></script>
</head>
```

--Javascript (from script.js):

```
"use strict";

function main() {
    //Create render and camera objects; both work when not using controls

    const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

    // create scene, GLTFLoader, run animate function
}
const obj_returned = main();
```

I've tried a few different styles of the script command:

`<script type="module"> import { OrbitControls } from "https://unpkg.com/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js"; </script>`

This gives the `Uncaught ReferenceError: OrbitControls is not defined` error,

`<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js">`

produces the same error, and

`<script src="https://unpkg.com/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>`

This actually gives the same error plus `Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module`, I think due to the missing `type="module"` flag.

All local files are in the same directory.

I've looked at several other examples of this sort of thing to see what I'm missing (like [here](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_camera_cinematic), [here](https://gist.github.com/bellbind/c4f8c502fcacbe29422e5ac315273858#file-z-monster-jpg), [here](https://threejs.org/examples/#misc_controls_orbit), [the three.js documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls), [the OrbitControls source code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js), and several others).

I'm *very* new to JS and HTML, so 1) it's likely something very obvious and 2) if it's not trivial / a typo, I would appreciate a little explanation as to why this doesn't work so I can avoid similar mistakes in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you want to use any js package manager (just link js file to your page) - use 'js' folders in threejs distribution, not 'jsm'. 'Jsm' folders contains module for using with webpack or other managers.

Comment: @SalientBrain Thanks for your response! If I understand correctly, your suggestion is to simply modify the import URL to be `/js/controls/OrbitControls.js`? That gives me a `SyntaxError: import not found` error for OrbitControls in addition to the reference error mentioned in my question (though that address seems to be correct). Is there just a better way of doing these imports in general?

Comment: @LvP did you solve this? I got the exact same problem